# Base64 encoding of ByteArrays in Flex 4

Tags: encoding, flex4, arrays

How do I do this in Flex 4

```
var b64String:String = Base64.encodeByteArray(bytearray);
```

I get Access of undefined property Base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 doesn't come with Flex by default. You need to include [this script](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/util/Base64.as).